# Opening an existing class in Redmine Plugin file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, redmine-plugins

I'm writing a plugin on Redmine.

I want to add a new method inside a existing controller of Redmine. The controller name is Repositories.

I wrote in *repositories.rb* the following code:

```
class RepositoriesController < ApplicationController

  def exec_client
    ...
  end

end
```

In *routes.rb* I put:

```
match '/projects/:id/repository', :controller => 'Repositories', :action => 'exec_client', :via => :post
```

In my view *navigation.html.erb* I wrote:

```
<%= button_to_function l(:gerar_build_project), remote_function(:action => 'exec_client', :controller => 'Repositories')%>
```

The code of class RepositoriesController was originally written on the file repositories_controller.rb.

But, when I click in my button I've created in my view, I get the following message:

**AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'exec_client' could not be found for RepositoriesController):**

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend a class in a Redmine plugin and add new methods, you need to follow these steps:

In the path plugin/lib/client I created the file client.rb

```
#encoding: UTF-8
module RepositoriesPatch
    require_dependency 'repositories_controller'
    def self.included(base)
      base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    end
end

module InstanceMethods
  require_dependency 'repositories_controller'
  def exec_client
    [....]
  end
end

Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  RepositoriesController.send(:include, RepositoriesPatch)
end
```

Above I created a patch which a new function to repositores_controller and have inserted it using the command .send

In init.rb I put:

```
  Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
    RepositoriesController.send(:include, RepositoriesPatch)
  end
```

The rest stood the same. Hope this can be useful to someone. Thanks!